# How to access physical addresses from user space in Linux?

Tags: linux, memory, arm, memory-address, memory-mapping

On a ARM based system running Linux, I have a device that's memory mapped to a physical address. From a user space program where all addresses are virtual, how can I read content from this address?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can map a device file to a user process memory using `mmap(2)` system call. Usually, device files are mappings of physical memory to the file system.
Otherwise, you have to write a kernel module which creates such a file or provides a way to map the needed memory to a user process.

Another way is remapping parts of `/dev/mem` to a user memory.

Edit:
Example of mmaping `/dev/mem` (this program must have access to `/dev/mem`, e.g. have root rights):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc < 3) {
        printf("Usage: %s <phys_addr> <offset>\n", argv[0]);
        return 0;
    }

    off_t offset = strtoul(argv[1], NULL, 0);
    size_t len = strtoul(argv[2], NULL, 0);

    // Truncate offset to a multiple of the page size, or mmap will fail.
    size_t pagesize = sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE);
    off_t page_base = (offset / pagesize) * pagesize;
    off_t page_offset = offset - page_base;

    int fd = open("/dev/mem", O_SYNC);
    unsigned char *mem = mmap(NULL, page_offset + len, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, page_base);
    if (mem == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("Can't map memory");
        return -1;
    }

    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        printf("%02x ", (int)mem[page_offset + i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Notes: 1) `CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM` and `nopat` are required to view RAM modifications on x86 2) For IO operations, you likely want to use `MAP_SHARED` to make the writes immediate. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45127890/895245

Answer (score 60):

**`busybox devmem`**

`busybox devmem` is a tiny CLI utility that mmaps `/dev/mem`.

You can get it in Ubuntu with: `sudo apt-get install busybox`

Usage: read 4 bytes from the physical address `0x12345678`:

```
sudo busybox devmem 0x12345678
```

Write `0x9abcdef0` to that address:

```
sudo busybox devmem 0x12345678 w 0x9abcdef0
```

Source: https://github.com/mirror/busybox/blob/1_27_2/miscutils/devmem.c#L85

**mmap `MAP_SHARED`**

When mmapping `/dev/mem`, you likely want to use:

```
open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR | O_SYNC);
mmap(..., PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, ...)
```

`MAP_SHARED` makes writes go to physical memory immediately, which makes it easier to observe, and makes more sense for hardware register writes.

**`CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM` and `nopat`**

To use `/dev/mem` to view and modify regular RAM on kernel v4.9, you must fist:

- disable `CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM` (set by default on Ubuntu 17.04)
- pass the `nopat` kernel command line option for x86

IO ports still work without those.

See also: [mmap of /dev/mem fails with invalid argument for virt_to_phys address, but address is page aligned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39134990/mmap-of-dev-mem-fails-with-invalid-argument-for-virt-to-phys-address-but-addre/45127582#45127582)

**Cache flushing**

If you try to write to RAM instead of a register, the memory may be cached by the CPU: [How to flush the CPU cache for a region of address space in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22701352/how-to-flush-the-cpu-cache-for-a-region-of-address-space-in-linux) and I don't see a very portable / easy way to flush it or mark the region as uncacheable:

- [How to write kernel space memory (physical address) to a file using O_DIRECT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439082/how-to-write-kernel-space-memory-physical-address-to-a-file-using-o-direct)
- [How to flush the CPU cache for a region of address space in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22701352/how-to-flush-the-cpu-cache-for-a-region-of-address-space-in-linux)
- [Is it possible to allocate, in user space, a non cacheable block of memory on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885658/is-it-possible-to-allocate-in-user-space-a-non-cacheable-block-of-memory-on-li)

So maybe `/dev/mem` can't be used reliably to pass memory buffers to devices?

This can't be observed in QEMU unfortunately, since QEMU does not simulate caches.

**How to test it out**

Now for the fun part. Here are a few cool setups:

- [Userland memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17021214/how-to-decode-proc-pid-pagemap-entries-in-linux/45126141#45126141)

  - allocate `volatile` variable on an userland process
  - get the physical address with `/proc/<pid>/maps` + `/proc/<pid>/pagemap`
  - modify the value at the physical address with `devmem`, and watch the userland process react
- [Kernelland memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39134990/mmap-of-dev-mem-fails-with-invalid-argument-for-virt-to-phys-address-but-addre/45127582#45127582)

  - allocate kernel memory with `kmalloc`
  - get the physical address with `virt_to_phys` and pass it back to userland
  - modify the physical address with `devmem`
  - query the value from the kernel module
- [IO mem and QEMU virtual platform device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28315265/how-to-add-a-new-device-in-qemu-source-code/44612957#44612957)

  - create a platform device with known physical register addresses
  - use `devmem` to write to the register
  - watch `printf`s come out of the virtual device in response

**Bonus: determine the physical address for a virtual address**

[Is there any API for determining the physical address from virtual address in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748492/is-there-any-api-for-determining-the-physical-address-from-virtual-address-in-li/45128487#45128487)

Comment: I found busybox is super handy. Thanks for sharing.