# u-boot: how to access 'bootcount' from linux userspace?

Tags: c, beagleboneblack, u-boot

I'm trying to use [u-boot's "bootcount" feature](http://www.denx.de/wiki/view/DULG/UBootBootCountLimit) to detect multiple failed attempts to boot, on a TI am335x device (e.g. beaglebone black.)  On TI/ Davinci platform, the bootcount value is stored in the `RTC_SCRATCH2` register ([source](http://git.ti.com/ti-u-boot/ti-u-boot/blobs/master/drivers/bootcount/bootcount_davinci.c)).  However on the linux side, I can't find any driver that exposes bootcount as a sysfs node or device, as a means of reading and resetting the value.  So it seems this is not supported in the (mainline) kernel, but I'm wondering if it's possible from userspace?

Ref:

- https://e2e.ti.com/support/embedded/linux/f/354/t/542737
- https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/am335x-read-and-write-some-rtc-registers-4175519888/

## EDIT: a working implementation

Here's the meat of a working solution, however I have one question (see below...)

```
int fd = open("/dev/mem", O_SYNC | O_RDWR);
unsigned char *mem = mmap(NULL, page_offset + len, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, page_base);
if (mem == MAP_FAILED) {
    perror("Can't map memory");
    return -1;
}

unsigned char *scratch2 = mem + page_offset;

// Read value from SCRATCH2, verify magic number
uint32_t val = *(uint32_t *)scratch2;
//printf("%08" PRIx32 "\n", val);

// low two bytes are the value, high two bytes are magic
if ((val & 0xffff0000) != (BOOTCOUNT_MAGIC & 0xffff0000)) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Error: BOOTCOUNT_MAGIC does not match\n");
  return -1;
}

printf("%d\n", (uint16_t)(val & 0x0000ffff));
```

Now, if I cast the `mmap`'d memory as a `uint32_t *`  (shown below,) to avoid avoid later type casts, the value I read back is incorrect (the `BOOTCOUNT_MAGIC` doesn't match):

```
uint32_t *mem = mmap(NULL, page_offset + len, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, page_base);

uint32_t *scratch2 = mem + page_offset;

// Read value from SCRATCH2, verify magic number
uint32_t val = *scratch2;
//printf("%08" PRIx32 "\n", val);

// low two bytes are the value, high two bytes are magic
if ((val & 0xffff0000) != (BOOTCOUNT_MAGIC & 0xffff0000)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: BOOTCOUNT_MAGIC does not match\n");
    return -1;
}

printf("%d\n", (uint16_t)(val & 0x0000ffff));
```

Shouldn't `val` still hold the same value when I use `uint32_t *mem`?

Full source can be [found on Github](https://github.com/VoltServer/uboot-davinci-bootcount/blob/c4cf2f49bf83d1c88e24eb24b554629be3a88c6d/src/bootcount.c).

Comment: Learn how to use **devmem2.c**.

Comment: Assuming your code is derived from devmem2.c, then removing the copyright notice is improper or worse.

Comment: *"it doesn't work"* -- That's an inadequate problem description.  Considering your job title, you should be able to solve this yourself if you bother to debug the code by reporting the locations that the program tries to access.

Comment: Fair, I clarified what "does not work."  Let me suggest that "Considering your title you should be able to solve this" is less than constructive feedback for a Q&A forum.  I'm a novice when it comes to C.  With the help of [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12041352/213983), I did in fact come up with a working solution (first example.)

Comment: I just looked at devmem2.c just in case the SO answer I referenced copied from there.  They are completely different - even the `open("/dev/mem"` and the `mmap()` lines do not appear to be copies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Shouldn't `val` still hold the same value when I use `uint32_t *mem`?

If you had used proper pointer arithmetic (which you did not), then you would have gotten the correct results.

In a C expression of `<pointer> + <scaler>`, the `<scaler>` is taken to represent a quantity with the same size as the pointer type (e.g. `sizeof(struct foo)`).
Only when the pointer is a byte pointer would the `<scaler>` represent a byte count.

If we have an array `x` consisting of 100 elements of a structure, e.g.

```
struct foo x[100];
```

the name of the array can be used as a pointer.
So the address of tenth element of the array can be referenced either as `&x[9]` or `(x + 9)`.

---

So in your first example of code

```
unsigned char *mem ...
```

`mem` is declared as a byte pointer.
So the pointer calculation in

```
unsigned char *scratch2 = mem + page_offset;
```

produces the results you expect, since `sizeof(unsigned char)` is 1 (byte), and `page_offset` is expressed in number of bytes.

---

However in your second code example

```
uint32_t *mem  ...
```

`mem` is declared as a pointer to a 4-byte word.
So the identical pointer calculation in

```
unsigned char *scratch2 = mem + page_offset;
```

is really equivalent to

```
unsigned char *scratch2 = (unsigned char *)mem + (sizeof(uint32_t) * page_offset);
```

where `sizeof(uint32_t)` is 4 (bytes), and the offset applied is quadruple what you intended.
That's because `page_offset` is still a number of bytes, but in the original expression is treated as a scaler count of the pointer type, which is a 4-byte word.
You cannot simply change the pointer type (i.e. from a `char` to an `int`), and expect the pointer arithmetic to be unaffected.
When you change `mem` to type `uint32_t *`, the pointer calculation needs to re-coded to convert the byte offset to a quad-byte offset:

```
unsigned char *scratch2 = mem + (page_offset / sizeof(uint32_t));
```

---

You could confirm these statements (or debug your code) by using **printf()**  to report the values of `mem`, `scratch2`, and other pointer calculations.